issue with bootstrap conflict used with WebpackJS and shadow Dom
I have widget app using boostrap and bootstrap icons
all this is bundled via Webpack js 5
I had huge difficulties to make bootstrap icons to be loaded correctly but now it's working.
the only problem remaining is the conflict with boostrap framework which is overriding styles of the websites where I do put the widget js script.
I'm using shadow dom system but I think i'm missing something somewhere. I think the problem comes from bootstrap and bootstrap icons being loaded globally in index.js.
please find my files attached
thanks for helping me fix this

webpack config

     const path = require('path');
     const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
     const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
     const webpack = require('webpack');
     module.exports = {
       entry: './src/index.js',
       output: {
         filename: 'widget-bundle.js',
         path: path.resolve(dirname, 'dist'),
       },
       module: {
         rules: [
           {
             test: /\.js$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
             use: {
               loader: 'babel-loader',
               options: {
                 presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
               },
             },
           },
         {
             test: /\.scss$/,
             use: [
               MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
               'css-loader',
               'sass-loader'
             ]
           },    
           {
                 test: /\.css$/,
                 use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            },
            {
                 test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                 type: "asset/inline",
            }
       ],
       },
       plugins: [
         new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
           filename: 'widget.css',
         }),
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           template: './src/index.html',
           inject: 'head'
         }),
         new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: 'jquery',
           jQuery: 'jquery',
         }),      
       ],
       resolve: {
         alias: {
           'bootstrap-icons': path.resolve(dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap-icons'),
           'bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
        },
       },
     };
 

index.js

     import $ from 'jquery';
     window.$ = window.jQuery = $; // Make jQuery available globally
     import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
     import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
     import './css/widget.css';
     import { initWidget } from './js/widget';
     const widgetId = document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-widgetid');
     if (widgetId) {
       initWidget(widgetId);
     } else {
       console.error('Widget ID not provided');
     }
 

widget.js

     import { u } from './config';
     //import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
     //import '../css/widget.css';
     export function initWidget(widgetId) {
       const shadowHost = document.createElement('div');
       document.body.appendChild(shadowHost);
       const shadowRoot = shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
       const widgetContainer = document.createElement('div');
       widgetContainer.id = 'widget-container';
       const buttonIcon = document.createElement('button');
       buttonIcon.className = 'btn btn-primary widget-icon';
       buttonIcon.innerHTML = '';
       const form = document.createElement('div');
       form.className = 'widget-form d-none';
       form.innerHTML = 
           
             Name
             
           
           
             Email
             
           
           Submit
         ;
       widgetContainer.appendChild(buttonIcon);
       widgetContainer.appendChild(form);
       const styles = document.createElement('style');
       styles.textContent = @import url('${u}/dist/widget.css');;
       shadowRoot.appendChild(styles);
       shadowRoot.appendChild(widgetContainer);
       buttonIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
         form.classList.toggle('d-none');
       });
       // Load settings via AJAX
       $.ajax({
         url: ${u}/proxy.php,
         method: 'GET',
         data: { widgetId },
         success: function(response) {
           // Apply settings to the widget
           console.log('Widget settings:', response);
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           console.error('Error loading widget settings:', error);
         }
       });
     }
 

config.js

     const protocol = 'https://';
     const host = 'domain.com';
     const dir = '/widget-v2';
     export const u = protocol + host + dir
 

package.json

     {
       "name": "widget-v2",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "description": "",
       "main": "index.js",
       "scripts": {
         "build": "webpack --mode production",
         "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch"
       },
       "keywords": [],
       "author": "",
       "license": "ISC",
       "devDependencies": {
         "@babel/core": "^7.24.7",
         "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.7",
         "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
         "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
         "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
         "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
         "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
         "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
         "sass": "^1.77.6",
         "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
         "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
         "to-string-loader": "^1.2.0",
         "webpack": "^5.92.1",
         "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
       },
       "dependencies": {
         "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
         "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
         "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
         "jquery": "^3.7.1",
         "raw-loader": "^4.0.2"
       }
     }
 



no solution so far

so the problem is in the webpack config file and the rules to handle css
code #1 loads the bootstrap icons and boostrap css but is making conflict with the existing css in the main page (it's overriding body background color)
code #2 is not producing conflict for the exisisting css but is not loading boostrap icons and boostrap
so I need a code to solve this
Code #1:{ test: /.css$/, use: ['style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true, }, }, 'postcss-loader', ], },
Code #2:{ test: /.css$/, use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'], },
